# Can the General Relativity Energy Relation of the Static Patch of deSitter Space be Quantized?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, metric-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

I am trying to play around with quantum field theory in de Sitter space. In reading a lecture about General Relativity, I found that, in the static patch of de Sitter space, the conserved quantity of energy can be related to angular momentum like so: $$E^2 = V_{\text{eff}}(r) + \frac{d^2r}{d\sigma^2}$$
where $$V_{\text{eff}}(r) = 1 - \frac{\Lambda r^{2}}{3} + \frac{l^2}{r^2} - \frac{\Lambda l^2}{3}$$
${\Lambda}$ is the cosmological constant and *l* is the angular momentum. I was wondering, similarly to how Oskar Klein and Walter Gordon took the energy-momentum relation from Minkowski spacetime, $$E^2 = (\overrightarrow{p}c)^2 + (m_0c^2)^2$$ and changed energy and momentum to operators that would accept a scalar wavefunction to obtain the Klein-Gordon equation. In the same way, could I change the energy and angular momentum factors in my first equation to their quantum operator equivalents and have them act on a kind of wavefunction? And since the de Sitter space evolves from the vacuum solution to the Einstein field equation $$R_{\mu\nu}=+{\Lambda}g_{\mu\nu}$$ is obviously devoid of matter particles, what kind of boson, if any, might satisfy this quantized version of the first energy equation?

Comment: Hint: Try to find the Killing vectors (KV) of de-Sitter space-time. The conserved energy $E$ can be associated to some KV $T_a$ as $E=T_au^a$ where $u$ is the particle geodesic vector. Then see if the remaining part of your first equation can be written in terms of other KVs. Then "elevate" those KVs to operators. Will you find any similarity with KG field on background de-Sitter spacetime?

Comment: @KP99, I understand that the energy operator can be expressed as $\hat{E} = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. Would I be correct in saying that $\hat{E} = \hat{T}_t = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$? Or would it be  $\hat{E}u_t = \hat{T}_t = -i\hbar u_t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ (multiplying the energy operator by the inverse geodesic vector $u_t$)?

Comment: The former looks correct... but there is a bit arbitrariness because if you have a unit time like vector field $u$ , you could equally set $\hat{E}=-i\hbar u^a\nabla_a$. I'll think about it and try to post an answer in the weekend